# lpr won't print multiple files

Tags: printing, pdf

As far as I know, you can print multiple files with a single `lpr` command, and if I issue a command like this

```
lpr fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

both `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt` are printed. But if I write:

```
lpr fileA.pdf fileB.pdf
```

only `fileB.pdf` is printed.

What do I do wrong?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

**EDIT**

After printing, `/var/log/cups/access_log` contains this:

```
localhost - - [17/Dec/2020:19:39:19 +0100] "POST /printers/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_6970_7BE7A4_ HTTP/1.1" 200 490 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [17/Dec/2020:19:39:19 +0100] "POST /printers/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_6970_7BE7A4_ HTTP/1.1" 200 6990 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [17/Dec/2020:19:39:19 +0100] "POST /printers/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_6970_7BE7A4_ HTTP/1.1" 200 7085 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - root [17/Dec/2020:19:39:20 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 306 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [17/Dec/2020:19:39:21 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 306 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
```

And `/var/log/cups/error_log` contains this:

```
E [17/Dec/2020:19:39:20 +0100] [Job 261] File \'\' not found
```

Comment: Please add `lpr` logs with `$ tail -f /var/log/lpr.log`

Comment: There is no `/var/log/lpr.log` on my computer.

Comment: @EsmaeelE: There is, however, a `/var/log/cups` folder with contents that I've added to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I re-posted this question two years later, and the upshot was that this is a bug in CUPS.

Details are here: [CUPS: lp command only prints last file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444926/cups-lp-command-only-prints-last-file)

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste all the files you want to print into a new empty folder.
Open a terminal and navigate to that folder.

```
lpr *
```

This should work.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. Writing `lpr *` in a folder with two files is exactly the same as writing `lpr first-file second-file`.