# CUPS: lp command only prints last file

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I try to print two files from the command line thus:

```
$ lp alpha.txt beta.txt
```

The `lpq` command gives this output:

```
$ lpq
HP_OfficeJet_Pro_6970_7BE7A4 is ready
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     claus   56      alpha.txt                       2048 bytes
```

Here, it mentions only the file `alpha.txt`. However, only the file `beta.txt` is actually printed. `alpha.txt` is not printed.

What might be the reason for that?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with CUPS 2.4.1.

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

If I use `lp` to print more than one file, these messages appear the `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
W [13/Dec/2022:16:22:19 +0100] [Job 61] /tmp/12345639a6b95: file is damaged
W [13/Dec/2022:16:22:19 +0100] [Job 61] /tmp/12345639a6b95 (offset 14802): xref not found
W [13/Dec/2022:16:22:19 +0100] [Job 61] /tmp/12345639a6b95: Attempting to reconstruct cross-reference table
```

**FURTHER INFORMATION 2**

The file name in the log starts with 12345. This neat pattern is a coincidence. Repeated attempts show that the first 5 digits of the filename appear to be the hexadecimal value of the PID of the `gstoraster` CUPS filter that runs as part of the printing process. So perhaps, the problem lies with that filter.

Comment: I made a few tests with multiple files to Boomaga printer driver and I got an **Error on 551: Can't read genNum** message. You can try to print the files like this: `cat alpha.txt beta.txt | lp`.

Comment: @FedKad: Unfortunately, the solution with `cat` doesn't work if I'm printing a mixture of .txt and .pdf files. Also, I'll have to manually insert page breaks between the files.

Comment: Check if you have a shell alias for that command that maybe doesn't properly forward all arguments that it gets to the underlying command. That happened to me more than once.

Comment: @HuHa: That can't be the problem. As you see, the `lpq` command lists the file `alpha.txt`, but `beta.txt` is the file that's actually printed. So somehow the print system knows about both files.

Comment: Could you check `which lp` and try `lp -- alpha.txt beta.txt`

Comment: Please try and see if `for f in "alpha.txt" "beta.txt"; do lp "$f"; done`  makes a difference ... i.e. using the loop to send each file as a separate single argument.

Comment: @user.dz: `which lp` prints `/usr/bin/lp`. Using `lp -- alpha.txt beta.txt` makes no difference.

@Raffa: Issuing two `lp` commands causes both files to be printed; and this is, of course, a useful substitute. However, the documentation for `lp` says that it should be possible to print multiple files using one command, so I wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my additions to the original post.

Comment: It seems that `alpha.txt` is not really a plain text file and it is damaged … "missing external reference” usually happens with binary files e.g. images … Test with `echo "text 1" > file1.txt && echo "text 2" > file2.txt && lp file1.txt file2.txt` and see how it goes.

Comment: @Raffa: `alpha.txt` is absolutely a plain text file. I created it exactly as you suggest, and a hex dump of the file shows it as entirely a plain text file. Anyway, the error message is not "missing external reference" but "xref not found", which could be an internal reference created by `gstoraster`, if that is indeed the problem filter, as I suggested in my latest addition to the post.

Comment: "xref" is not necessarily "external reference". It can simply mean "cross reference".

Comment: Oh, I see … could be corrupted printer/spooler … So probably removing and reinstalling both cups and ghostscript might fix it.

Comment: @Raffa: I doubt it. I recently reinstalled everything on my computer, and I had the problem both before and after the reinstallation. Anyway, I've discovered that CUPS has a mailing list for this kind of problem. Maybe I should try there. Anyway, thank you for your kind effort.

Comment: @oz1cz Please, update this Q&A with more information as it becomes available. Obviously, it looks that there is bug in the `lp` software.

Comment: @FedKad: I will. I've asked the same question on a CUPS mailing list, but so far I've had no reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I posted the question on the CUPS mailing list and got this answer from Helge Blischke:

> Well, I do not completely understand what is going on here,
> but I at least have a hypothesis I’ll try to explain here.
>
> What I’ve learned from your log file is:
>
> —  Your printer is set up using an emulation of implicit classes (developed by openprinting to make the functionality of
> implicit classes implemented in cups 1.x available in cups 2.x) based on the functionality off cups-browsed.
>
> This approach seems - to me at least - rather complicated, and the key feature is that the backend
> "implicitclass", which is used here, collects all jobs for the printer in question by executing the complete
> filter chain for each job file.
>
> —  This implies e.g. for PDF files (the cups-filter strategy is to convert all files to be printed
> at least intermediately to PDF using the pdftopdf filter, which - to my experience - appends an
> additional EOF character (^Z, I think) to each PDF file.
>
> —  Somewhere in the filter chain executed by the implicitclass backend the PDFs are processed
> by routines implemented in the QPDF library, which leads to PDF error messages caused
> by the intermediate ^Z characters — that is at least what I deduct from the various
> messages.
>
> As I myself do not use the cups-filters package (even on my Linux box I don’t), I have no chance
> to digest further into this problem.but I think my thesis cant’t be completely wrong.

So, apparently, it's a rather complicated bug in CUPS, and I'll just have to live with it.